# Align two inline-block so that they remain on the same line

Tags: css

I have a situation like in `http://jsfiddle.net/paolobenve/gh577vg3/6/`:

```
<div style="width: 100%;border: 3px solid #73AD21;">Container div<br>
  <span style="display: inline-block;
           position:relative;
           border:1px solid green;
           width: 1em;">
    T
  </span>
  <span style="display: inline-block;position:relative;border:1px solid green;">
     This asdfa sdf asdfa sdfa sdfa da da asd asdasdf adfa asfd
     asd s sd asd fasdf asdf asd asdf asd asd asd sdsdf sdsdf asd
     asd asd sdsdf sdsdf asd asd asd sdsdf sd sa
  </span>
</div>
```

two consecutive inline-blocks, the first has fixed width, the second spans along the remaining space.

If the viewport width becomes narrower (or if the text in the second span becomes longer), the second span tends to occupy all the viewport width, and consecuently remains below the first span.

I want the second span to remain always at the right of the first, independently of viewport width or text length.

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Comment: if you set the containing div to a pixel amount you can

Comment: I cannot, the web page must be responsive

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you add a max-width to the second span such that the style appear like this:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The max-width will ensure that the second span won't expand beyond the given figure. Using a percentage makes it more dynamic/responsive but you could also use px. You could also add a max-width to the first span so that they both have restrictions.

PS, the word-wrap makes sure that no words hang out of the span (if you happen to have a really long word).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently everything is ok adding `white-space: nowrap;` to the container *div* and `white-space: normal;` to the second *span*, see http://jsfiddle.net/paolobenve/gh577vg3/7/